# Can I extend part of an Interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have an interface:

```js
// I get this from an external library so I have no control over it
interface Balloon {
  diameter: number;
  color: "red" | "blue" | "green";
}
```

And I want to create my own interface that looks like this:

```js
interface Shirt {
  size: "m" | "l" | "xl";
  color: "red" | "blue" | "green";
}
```

My question is whether it is possible to 'take' the color part from Balloon and inject it into Shirt, so I get something like this:

```js
interface Shirt {
  size: "m" | "l" | "xl";
  color: Balloon.color; // I know this is wrong but it is to illustrate what I want to achieve
}
```

Comment: Sure. `color: Balloon['color']`

Comment: @ritaj you can post this as an answer

Comment: Yes, very simple and elegant solution and very fast response, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a base interface:

```js
interface WithColor {
    color: "red" | "blue" | "green";
}

interface Shirt extends WithColor {
  size: "m" | "l" | "xl";
}
```

Or you could make `Color` an enum:

```js
enum Color {
    RED = "red",
    BLUE = "blue",
    GREEN = "green",
}

interface Shirt {
  size: "m" | "l" | "xl";
  color: Color;
}
```

...or even a combination of these two.

while i'd not advise to use types of other interfaces, because that poses a maintainability risk, if you happen to change it on the source interface, this is also a possible way:

```js
interface Shirt {
  size: "m" | "l" | "xl";
  color: "red" | "blue" | "green";
}

interface Balloon {
  size: "m" | "l" | "xl";
  color: Shirt["color"];
}
```

Comment: The question was about using property type from an existing interface

Comment: @ritaj while that is true, that would not be a very good idea to do, as it would reduce maintainability. however, i added the requested solution to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
interface Balloon {
    diameter: number;
    color: "red" | "blue" | "green";
}


type Shirt = {
    size: "m" | "l" | "xl";
} & Pick<Balloon, 'color'>

type Check = Shirt['color'] // "red" | "blue" | "green"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwDYYPbZMgbwChlTkATYOAWwkigC5kQBXagI2gG4SyFscjZACIoEcsOQAfEewwsIkmcIDmYiCGE8AvkT1gAngAcUAZQAWwKGGQBeQr1IBnYAC8ITYdSUiMP4QAefjrIAGTIAArACADWADzoWLggADTIAOT8gukAfPrGKADC5hCxdsgWVmAA2pkC2FDpALrIAPStImIS0rLyij2q6pp6QA)

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) you can find more utility types